# Javascript Function sometimes loops itself into an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I have made a while function that works correctly about half the time. Sometimes though it will not load the function at all or get stuck loading the next part of the function doing one of its loops. There is nothing wrong with the syntax as far as I can see, but I am still new to Javascript. I can't see anywhere in the code that could lead itself into thinking that it is stuck in an infinite loop. Well here is my code if you could help that would be awesome.

```
var dragHunt = true; 
var hitOrMiss = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); 
var dmgOnHit = 0;
var totalDmg = 0;
var playerHealth= 0;
var dragHitOrMiss = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1.5);
var dragDmg= 0;

while(dragHunt){
if(hitOrMiss){
    dmgOnHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    alert("You hit the dragon, the luck is with you today. You did " + dmgOnHit + " damage!");
    totalDmg += dmgOnHit;

    if(totalDmg >= 20){
        alert("You did it! You have killed the dragon. The hunt was successful!");
        dragHunt=false;
    }
    else{
        hitOrMiss = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    }
}
else{
    if(dragHitOrMiss){
        dragDmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
        alert("The Dragon hit you for " + dragDmg + " damage!");
        playerHealth += dragDmg;

        if(playerHealth >= 80){
            alert("The dragon has burnt you to a crisp. You stood no chance against the ferocious beast.");
            dragHunt=false;
        }
        else{
            hitOrMiss = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: The problem seems when both `hitOrMiss` and `dragHitOrMiss` are false.

Answer (score 1):

I see what your problem is. You create an infinite loop because **hitOrMiss** is always false as well as **dragHitOrMiss**. So, basically, dragHunt is never changing

Answer (score 0):

If dragHitOrMiss is effectively a constant, computed only at the top.  If it is false, and hitOrMiss becomes false, they will never be recomputed. 
When they are both false, you have:

```
dragHunt = true;
while(dragHunt) {
  if (false) { 
     // not executed
  else if (false) {
     // not executed
  }
}
```

Which is your endless loop.

If dragHitOrMiss is calculated as true at the top, then hitOrMiss is recalculated in each pass, which is why you only sometimes have an endless loop.

edit: You want your code to look more like this:

```
while(dragHunt) {
    var hitOrMiss = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if (hitOrMiss) {
        // The player hit the dragon code here.
    } else {
        // The Player missed the dragon; it gets a chance to hit the player instead
        var dragHitOrMiss = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1.5);
        if (dragHitOrMiss) {
            // Dragon hit you code here.
        }
    }
}
```

Each time you check if the player hits the dragon, you compute the hit/miss value.  Each time you check if the dragon hits the player, you compute that hit/miss value.  Notice the hitOrMiss and dragHitOrMiss values are no longer declared before the dragHunt loop, but actually declared and computed just before being used.

Comment: So what the code is doing is it generates hitOrMiss and dragHitOrMiss as constants because they are only computed once. How do I go about fixing this from happening.

Comment: You need to either recompute the (drag)hitOrMiss values after you've used them, or generate them just before you use them.  I'll update my answer to demonstrate this.